`request` parameter in Django - HTTPRequest or WSGIRequest
All of Django documentation says request is of type django.http.request.HTTPRequest. I use NGINX -> Waitress WSGI in my development, and I see see request is django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest which inherits directly from HTTPRequest. I understand that Django must always run under WSGI, if so a request will always be WSGIRequest. So why does Django documentation always use HTTPRequest?

A request in Django will not always be a WSGIRequest. Django currently supports two interfaces being Web Server Gateway Interface (WSGI) and Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface (ASGI) and can be deployed with either. Corresponding to these there's a django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest class and a django.core.handlers.asgi.ASGIRequest class.
Depending on how Django is deployed the request will be an instance of either of them. Both of these classes inherit from HttpRequest so that Django as a framework can then expose a common type of object to its users. If Django supports more interfaces in the future it is possible that there would be a request class for them as well.
